# SQL get all related records

Tags: postgresql, join

I have the following two tables in PostgreSQL database:

```
records:
    id
    name --string

related_records:
    id
    record_id --id of original record
    related_id --id of related record
```

One record can have multiple related records and that relation is stored in "related_records" table.

I'm trying to create a query that returns the result with all related records when I search by name like this:

```
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE name LIKE 'Record 1';
```

How can I extend the query above to include all related records?

Example of desired output (records 1 and 2 are related):

```
id | name
-------------
 1 | Record 1
 2 | Record 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `EXISTS`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM records WHERE name = 'Record 1')
SELECT r.* FROM records r
WHERE r.name = (SELECT name FROM cte)
OR EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM related_records 
  WHERE related_id = r.id 
  AND record_id = (SELECT id FROM cte) 
)
```

or with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM records 
WHERE name = 'Record 1'
UNION ALL
SELECT r.* 
FROM records r 
INNER JOIN related_records rr ON rr.related_id = r.id
INNER JOIN records t ON t.id = rr.record_id
WHERE t.name = 'Record 1'
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=376402d4264065e80ef895a13e955614).